# Unexpected result from diff

Tags: zsh, macos, diff

Isn't the output contradictory? `diff` reports that the file is only in one of the locations. But then when I check with `ls`, the file is there. What is the reason? Is it because the filename contains non-ascii character? (ö)

```
% sudo diff -x .DS_Store /Volumes/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/junk /Users/niklasrosen/backup/seagateBackupPlus/junk | grep -v __MACOSX | grep -v niklasrosen 
    Password:
    Only in /Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/junk: slutlön2020.txt
% ls -al /Volumes/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/junk/slutlön2020.txt 
    -rwxr-xr-x  1 niklasrosen  staff  947 Aug 12  2020 /Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/junk/slutlön2020.txt
% ls -al /Users/niklasrosen/backup/seagateBackupPlus/junk/slutlön2020.txt 
    -rwxr-xr-x  1 niklasrosen  staff  947 Mar 14 03:36 /Users/niklasrosen/backup/seagateBackupPlus/junk/slutlön2020.txt
```

Further investigations show something must be explained:

```
% mkdir diffcheck
% cp /Volumes/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/junk/slutlön2020.txt diffcheck 
% ls -al /Volumes/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/junk/slutlön2020.txt 
        -rwxr-xr-x  1 niklasrosen  staff  947 Aug 12  2020 /Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/junk/slutlön2020.txt
% ls -al diffcheck 
        total 8
        drwxr-xr-x   3 niklasrosen  staff    96 Mar 14 10:27 .
        drwxr-xr-x+ 80 niklasrosen  staff  2560 Mar 14 10:27 ..
        -rwxr-xr-x   1 niklasrosen  staff   947 Mar 14 10:27 slutlön2020.txt
% diff /Volumes/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/junk/ diffcheck|grep ö      
        Only in diffcheck: slutlön2020.txt
% ls -al /Volumes/Seagate\ Backup\ Plus\ Drive/junk/slutlön2020.txt 
        -rwxr-xr-x  1 niklasrosen  staff  947 Aug 12  2020 /Volumes/Seagate Backup Plus Drive/junk/slutlön2020.txt
```

Comment: Try as I might, I cannot replicate.  If you feel it's the UTF-8 characters, try wrapping your filenames in single quotes.

Comment: [This maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26529400/10765659)?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes that looks likely. The files were copied around several different file systems (Windows, Linux, MacOS)